# BJT DC Analysis

Tags: transistors, bjt

I'm having more trouble then I should with a BJT question. Here is the question:

[image: BJT Question]

Normally I wouldn't know beta and would "assume beta large, thus I<sub>B</sub> = 0". I believe it is correct to assume the transistor is operating in the active region. Unfortunately I don't know either V<sub>E</sub> or V<sub>C</sub> so I'm unsure on how to proceed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're correct, in this case $$I_B \neq 0$$
$$I_C = I_B +I_E$$
Instead, you're going to want to use a few DC relations for an assumed active BJT. I'm also assuming that you're given a value for Vt. You're going to want to make a KVL loop with IE and IB and Vt. It should look like something like 
$$9V = I_E R_E + V_t + I_B R_B$$
with the added knowledge of
$$I_B = \frac{I_E}{\beta +1}$$
is enough to solve for IE. Use
$$I_C =\alpha I_E$$
to get the final current value. All thats left is to find the voltages using V=IR.

For the second part, of the question you'll have some algebra, but nothing overly complicated.

Comment: Aha I considered a KVL loop but knew it would result in two unknowns, I forgot I had a 2nd equation relating Ib and Ie, Cheers!